# Laravel (4) retrieve query stack trace

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need to optimize my Laravel queries and see many duplicates.

I logged them and see SQL, but I can not find the caller that produce them.

What I need is some sort of stack trace associated to each query, such that I can identify the point in my code that launch them and optimize it.

How can I do it?

I am using laravel 4, answers for laravel 4 are preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the debug bar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).
In the config file (application/config/debugbar.php) , you can set option 'backtrace'         to be true.

```
'options' => [
    'auth' => [
        'show_name' => false,   
    ],
    'db' => [
        'with_params'       => true,   
        'timeline'          => false,  
        **'backtrace'         => true,**  
        'explain' => [                 
            'enabled' => false,
            'types' => ['SELECT'],     
        ],
        'hints'             => true,    
    ],
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, you can create an event listener which logs the call stack every time a query is run.

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query) {
    Log::info('Query ran', debug_backtrace());
});
```

You could register this listener in perhaps `app/start/global.php`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/1.8), it will show queries executed on current view, next you can try find that piece of slow code inserting suspected parts in this type of brackets:

```
Debugbar::startMeasure('render','Time for rendering');
suspectedMethod();
Debugbar::stopMeasure('render');
```

Comment: hello, this way is useful only if I already suspect the method that trig the query, right?

Comment: You can take half of your methods that are called to this function and next half in another measure, check which take more time and repeat only in longer half ;)